# Google Places adding weird block on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places

I'm using Google Places searchNearby request to populate map. Every time I make Google Places get details request on marker tap a weird block appears on the bottom right side of the map. It looks the same as copyright at the bottom but empty. These blocks keep stacking on top of each other for every request.

The block has `gm-style-cc` class and is 12x14px.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a solution. It seems everytime you create new Places service, Google adds this white square to the map.

```
var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
```

I was doing this on each marker tap. The solution is to create it only once and then use the same instance.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, had the same problem, and also added it multiple times. However, just adding it once still draws one of those divs. Did you find a way to avoid it?

Comment: Sadly no ... but one square didn't bother me too much.